# v-if using boolean result from array [vue3]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I had a follow problem.

I need to show or hide contents using v-if, but i have my content on an array: this is my example.

```html
<v-expansion-panel v-for="item in flightOptionData" :key="item.type" elevation="0" class="rounded-lg foExpansion">
    <v-expansion-panel-title class="pa-3 bg-card" v-slot="{ open }" expand-icon="" collapse-icon="">
        <section class="foCard">
            <p>{{item.finalPrice}}</p>
            <p>{{item.number}}</p>
            <p v-if="true" class="nextDay">+1</p>
        </section>
    </v-expansion-panel-title>
</v-expansion-panel>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            flightOptionData: [
                { finalPrice: '5.431,00', number: 'A12314', overnight: true }, 
                { finalPrice: '5.431,00', number: 'A12314', overnight: false }
            ]
        }
</script>
```

I tried to solve at this way:

```html
<v-expansion-panel v-for="item in flightOptionData" :key="item.type" elevation="0" class="rounded-lg foExpansion">
    <v-expansion-panel-title class="pa-3 bg-card" v-slot="{ open }" expand-icon="" collapse-icon="">
        <section class="foCard">
             <p>{{item.finalPrice}}</p>
             <p>{{item.number}}</p>
             <p v-if="{{item.overnight}}" class="nextDay">+1</p>
        </section>
    </v-expansion-panel-title>
</v-expansion-panel>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            flightOptionData: [
                { finalPrice: '5.431,00', number: 'A12314', overnight: true }, 
                { finalPrice: '5.431,00', number: 'A12314', overnight: false }
            ]
        }
</script>
```

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code:

```html
<p v-if="{{item.overnight}}" class="nextDay">+1</p>
```

The correct syntax is:

```html
<p v-if="item.overnight" class="nextDay">+1</p>
```

Make sure to checkout out the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html) for Vue's template syntax